# How to transfer code from Console application to WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tcp

I want to transfer my code to a WinForms.

I know how to create buttons, text, etc... and how to operate them.

The problem is that I made my code in a windows application, and I want to transform it to WinForms application. I don't know how to copy and paste the whole code, cause in the WinForms application there is no main method..

Here is my code that I am trying to transfer to WinForms:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpClient connection = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 5000);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(connection.GetStream());
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(connection.GetStream());
       
            string name2 = "";
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your name and press submit");
                name2=Console.ReadLine();
                if (name2 != "")
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(name2);
                    break;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Loop is over");
            Thread t2 = new Thread(Reader);
           
            t2.IsBackground = true;
            t2.Start(connection);

            while (true)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
                sw.Flush();
            }
        }




    public static void Reader(object o)
    {
        TcpClient con = o as TcpClient;
        if (con == null)
            return;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(con.GetStream());
        while (true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the Form that I have created:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

      
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused a Windows Application IS Windows Forms...Can you explain what you are trying to achieve. EDIT: I just realised that you mean a Console Application to Windows Application. You need to do a bit of research into Windows Applications. You can't just copy/paste code from one to the other.

Comment: You probably want to go read some tutorials on Forms and events first, as different parts of your code need to go in different places on the form.

Comment: " cause in the window form application there is no main method." - er, yes there is - see `Program.cs` typically. But... you just call the code you want from the event handlers you want... I'm not sure where the problem lies.

Comment: how do i connect program.cs to where the functions with the text and buttons are?


how can i pass a string , for example, to a textfield.. instead of using Console.WriteLine()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows form application there is main method but it is in program.cs file and its starts your default form after you program starts execution.

You can add the the textbox in form and on button event get the text of the textbox.

```
String username = textboxusername.Text;
```

Similarly you can do all the things you want.

The code that you have written before was for console application and that is not the same for the windows form application.

You have to code differently for this.

Comment: So, do i simply put the whole code into the program cs and it will work?

Comment: no ... but instead you have to code for the events for button and page load... that depends on what exactly you want to do....